# alterar tamanho do carousel materialize

Tags: html, css, materialize, carousel

```css
body{
    margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
}
img{width: 100%;}
.pagina{widows: 100%; height: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-bottom: auto;}

.topo{width: 100%; height: 100px; border: 5px solid rgb(196, 20, 172);}
.carousel-fixed{height: 100px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
    <link rel='icon' href='imagens/icone.png' type=”image/x-icon”>
    <title>pagina inicial mobile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

 <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>         

</head>
<body>
    <div class="pagina">
        <header class="topo carousel carousel-slider center">            
            <div class="carousel-fixed-item center">
                
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item red white-text" href="#one!">
               <img src="imagens/01.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item amber white-text" href="#two!">
                        <img src="imagens/02.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item green white-text" href="#three!">
                        <img src="imagens/03.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item blue white-text" href="#four!">
                        <img src="imagens/04.jpg">
            </div>        
        </header>




    </div><!--/.pagina-->

  <script>
        var instance = M.Carousel.init({
    fullWidth: true,
    indicators: true
  });

  // Or with jQuery

  $('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({
    fullWidth: true,
    indicators: true
  });
      
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

olá gostaria de saber como eu altero o tamanho do meu carousel?
voces podem reparar que ta tomando minha tela quase toda. eu quero diminuir ela pra ums 250 px de altura .
to definindo um tamanho para o elemento pai do meu carousel mais nao ta funcionando
ja selecionei por varias classes que ta no cogigo e nada muda
confira na imagem ai ele ta de um tamanho que não to conseguindo alterar de jeito nenhum[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: poderia colocar a parte do código para podermos entender e poder ajudar

Comment: @DbaAlone ta ai o codigo .

Comment: assim fica mais fácil para verificar-mos

Comment: @DbaAlone eu tentei alterar o tamanho pelo css, selecionando por classes e em nada ele altera

Comment: Mas mudar como? Como vc quer que ele fique?

Comment: você colocou no header... eu tenho pouco conhecimento nessa parte porém até onde eu sei não é recomendado, tenta colocar em uma div principal para ver se ele pega esse atributo

Comment: @DbaAlone valeu  vou fazer um teste aqui

Comment: @hugocsl eu quero que ele fique do tamanho que eu  definir

Comment: @hugocsl voce pode reparar que ta tomando minha tela quase toda. eu quero diminuir ela pra  ums 250 px de altura

Comment: tente remover a propriedade fullWidth ou atribuir o valor false

Answer (score 1):

Vc está tentando redimensionar o *slider*, mas o correto normalmente é redimensionar o conteúdo dentro do *slider*. Então no coloque a altura na classe `topo` ou `carousel-fixed` coloque direto na imagem.

Eu coloquei o `100px` de altura no CSS direto para tag `img {}`, mas vc pode criar uma classe para colocar na imagem ou como achar melhor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
  <link rel='icon' href='imagens/icone.png' type=”image/x-icon”>
  <title>pagina inicial mobile</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>       

<style>
body{
  margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
}
img{width: 100%; height: 100px !important; object-fit: cover;}
.pagina{widows: 100%; height: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-bottom: auto;}

.topo{width: 100%; height: 100px; border: 5px solid rgb(196, 20, 172);}
.carousel-fixed{height: 100px;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="pagina">
      <header class="topo carousel carousel-slider center" style="height: 100px !important">            
          <div class="carousel-fixed-item center">
              
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item red white-text" href="#one!">
             <img src="https://picsum.photos/180/80">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item amber white-text" href="#two!">
                      <img src="https://picsum.photos/280/80">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item green white-text" href="#three!">
                      <img src="https://picsum.photos/180/80">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item blue white-text" href="#four!">
                      <img src="https://picsum.photos/280/80">
          </div>        
      </header>




  </div><!--/.pagina-->

<script>
      var instance = M.Carousel.init({
  fullWidth: true,
  indicators: true
});

// Or with jQuery

$('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({
  fullWidth: true,
  indicators: true
});
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```